# Select Last 20 latest Unique URLs from Table MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

Table Structure:

```
CREATE TABLE Test(
  ID PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  UserID INT,
  URL VARCHAR(255),
  MyTime DATETIME
)engine=myisam;
```

sample data:

```
 ID      UserID        URL                MyTime
 1        555        /index         2013-04-01 16:43:21
 2        777        /user          2013-03-01 16:43:21
 3        555        /user          2013-03-01 13:00:00
 4        555        /panel         2013-03-01 16:00:00
 5        555        /panel         2013-03-03 15:00:00
```

Now the query suppose to select all data where **URL** is not **/index** since **/index** is the home page so i want it to be ignored. Also the data it selects must be the **10** latest records ignoring **/index** data. It also must ignore the same URL if it falls in last 10 records, meaning if same user visited same page multiple times i only need one of them to be selected to be included in that **limit 10**. This would ignore **/panel** page that has **id 4**

so desired output for user **555** would be:

```
 ID      UserID        URL                MyTime
 3        555        /user          2013-03-01 13:00:00
 5        555        /panel         2013-03-03 15:00:00
```

My Try:

```
 SELECT *
 From Test
 WHERE URL NOT LIKE '%/index%' AND UserID = '555'
 ORDER BY MyTime DESC
 LIMIT 10
```

this query selects past **10** data but it includes the repeated **URL**, how do i get rid of repeated URL and only get the latest **10** records with Unique URL?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the GROUP BY function with a subQuery. If you only want to see the url you can just use the subQuery.

```
SELECT *
FROM Test INNER JOIN
  (SELECT url, max(mytime) maxtime
   FROM Test
   WHERE URL NOT LIKE '%/index%' 
   AND UserID = '555'
   GROUP BY url) n on test.url = n.url AND n.maxtime = Test.mytime
ORDER BY maxtime DESC
LIMIT 20
```

Comment: Dont know how i forgot about GROUP BY. I'm embarrassed. Thank you very much

Comment: @MattBusche how it will display other columns. You need to include those.

Comment: @AshReva I updated to allow the user to pull in all columns, but not sure if that's what he needed (although the question does suggest that)